# sql finding most recent date and working out WD to today

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have the following sql

```
  SELECT    Case.casekey,Case.StartDate,letter_sent.OfferreceivedDate, letter_sent.QuestionnairereceivedDate, letter_sent.ClientDate,letter_sent.ReceivedDate 
    FROM       Case WITH (nolock) INNER JOIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN letter_sent WITH (NOLOCK) ON Case.casekey = letter_sent.casekey
    WHERE
    letter_sent.OfferreceivedDate is not null and 
    letter_sent.QuestionnairereceivedDate is not null and  letter_sent.ClientDate is not null
    and letter_sent.ReceivedDate is not null
    ORDER BY Case.CaseStart DESC
```

i have a stored procedure wich looks at two date fields and calculates the total working days between them. i need to run my sql query and then out of the 5 date fields per record get the latest date and use this in my stored procedure to calculate how many working days between that date and today. i hope i have made this clear.

Comment: Which date? Please proof read your questions before posting. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TOP 1` statement to get most recent date row

```
SELECT   TOP 1  Case.casekey,Case.StartDate,letter_sent.MortgageOfferreceivedDate, letter_sent.QuestionnairereceivedDate, letter_sent.ClientDate,letter_sent.ReceivedDate 
    FROM       Case WITH (nolock) INNER JOIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN letter_sent WITH (NOLOCK) ON Case.casekey = letter_sent.casekey
    WHERE
    letter_sent.MortgageOfferreceivedDate is not null and 
    letter_sent.QuestionnairereceivedDate is not null and  letter_sent.ClientDateis not null
    and letter_sent.ReceivedDate is not null
    ORDER BY Case.CaseStart DESC
```